# The rrdcached is failed to stop

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I am using rrdtool-1.4.7-1 version of rrd tool.
In normal case, If all RRD data has been flushed then "clean shutdown; all RRDs flushed message" displays in syslog logs.
Below message will show when shutdown is performed.

```
Mar 21 10:36:28 rrdcached[52232]: caught SIGTERM
Mar 21 10:36:28 rrdcached[52232]: starting shutdown
Mar 21 10:36:29 rrdcached[52232]: clean shutdown; all RRDs flushed
Mar 21 10:36:29 rrdcached[52232]: removing journals
Mar 21 10:36:29 rrdcached[52232]: goodbye
```

but in problematic case, below message display and failed to stop rrd cached.

```
Mar 21 10:36:28 rrdcached[52232]: caught SIGTERM
Mar 21 10:36:28 rrdcached[52232]: starting shutdown
```

I have also checked on top logs and flushing is in progress on directory.
Please let me know in which case rrd cached daemon will fail to stop?

Comment: This is pretty hard to identify as there's not much information to work on.  My guess would be I/O issues writing to the RRD files.  Do you have a very large number of RRD files, or do you have particularly high caching times?  What parameters did you start rrdcached with?  Do you have a very slow disk?  How many updates are you sending per second? Does this happen every time, or only sometimes?  How often?  Are there any active connections?  If you start up and stop immediately, is it OK then? Etc.

Comment: There is no I/O issue and no large numbers of file of rrd files. Also we have checked no high caching time. we are using below command for flushing data.   /usr/bin/rrdcached -p /var/run/rrdtool/rrdcached/rrdcached.pid -l IP:port -w 3600 -z 10 -f 7200 -P FLUSH,FLUSHALL,PENDING,FORGET,STATS,QUEUE -F -b /opt/ -j /abc/xyz   Where IP and port will be some numeric value.

Comment: How long has rrdcached been running when you try and shut down?  How long have you waited for it to exit?  It's possible that there are just a very large number of updates pending write and it will exit in e.g. 10 minutes

Comment: Is there any way to find out that large number of update is pending?

Comment: You can see how much file space is used in the journal under /abc/xyz